Why is writing to gl_FragDepth fast when using constant values, but slow when using varying values?
I have the following situation: I want to transfer depth values from a framebuffer with 1 sample to a different framebuffer with 8 samples. I think, the only way how this can be accomplished is by drawing a full-screen quad and the GPU then assigns the depth values to all the sub samples. Here is an illustration:

The dots in the right image represent the 8 sub samples, the red lines show two triangles for rendering a full-screen quad to copy-over the depth values. To accomplish this, I am writing to gl_FragDepth in a fragment shader.
What puzzles me are the performance characteristics which I am observing:

Assigning a constant depth value, e.g., gl_FragDepth = 0.5;, runs fast.
Assigning varying depth values to gl_FragDepth shows much slower performance, costing as much as 1ms per frame for a resolution of 3840x2160 on an RTX 3070.

Why is the latter so much slower than the former?
The effect really seems to come from the assignment to gl_FragDepth, and not from sampling the other depth texture.
Source code (for the latter case) that leads to this +1ms can be as simple as follows:
gl_FragDepth = v_in.texCoords.x;

where v_in.texCoords are just the texture coordinates that are interpolated between vertex and fragment shader when drawing the two triangles of the full-screen quad. I would be grateful for an explanation of this effect.

You don't provide the SPIR-V code or the source code for that matter, so we're left to a lot of speculation.  There's several things that could explain this difference in performance.
gl_FragDepth = 0.5

If you assign a value to a constant, you're effectively allowing the compiler to just say "store a fixed value here".  The GPU may even have the ability to fill the frame buffer with a constant value, and if it can figure out you did this, it may decide to just use that instruction.  But that's entirely speculation, I suspect all it did is just do the equivalent to an immediate store into the depth buffer. This only requires a memory write to a location.
gl_FragDepth = v_in.texCoords.x;

When you load in what I assume to be a vertex output, that has to some how be transfered from the vertex shader invocation to the fragment shader.  If you don't use these output/input variables, the compiler may remove their use entirely, meaning any performance penalty that would have been paid by their existence now doesn't happen. It would not be surprising to me if there was some latency associated with this operation on some platforms.  In addition to that though, you have to read in v_in.texCoords and some interpolation must be happening before it's use if you don't apply the flat modifier, either adding additional operations before it's use, or necessitating more memory operations to facilitate it's usage.  So this requires more than a simple immediate store operation, a memory read, write and barycentric interpolation.
Regardless, even if some of this "new stuff" you're doing takes 1ms more, that doesn't mean the actual cost of what ever you're doing is 1ms.  GPUs have a lot of sources of latency, especially around memory operations.  GPUs will typically attempt to hide memory latency by running more than one set of subgroups on the same SIMD hardware, allowing one set of instructions to execute when another is waiting for a memory load to complete.   Basically, this 1ms could just be from some sort of latency, and would not necessarily increase linearly with more of the same types of operations in the second example.

The immediate store optimization could also turn into something resolvable at early-zs, given you don't actually need to run the shader to get the value, so it could pipeline with later layers of geometry (assuming there are some) much better than a late-ZS updated  value which needs the per-sample value to be determined and stored.
